# Fetch isn't setting cookies

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, cookies, fetch

I have a reactjs frontend running on root `/`.

On the same domain and server there is an Wordpress instance running under the default Wordpress slugs (`/wp-admin`, `/wp-json`, etc.). I already authenticate users via JWT over the WP API.

**The problem** is i need to get the Wordpress default auth cookies so users can switch between Wordpress and reactjs pages without logging in twice.

I started to add a second fetch on login which calls the `/login.php` route and posts login credentials as form-data. In Postman i get the body, headers and the auth cookies i need:

[image: Postman Fetch Example]

If i fetch this inside my react frontend i don't get the cookies, also the are not set and available under `document.cookie` or at the dev tools.

This is my fetch function in react which is returning the Dashboard Page as Response Data and a Status Code 200:

```
async handleCookies() {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('log', this.state.mail)
    formData.append('pwd', this.state.password)

    await fetch('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/wp-login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', Cache: 'no-cache' },
    })
     .then(response => response)
     .then(cookies => {
        alert(cookies)
     })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

**Expectation**: I expect to receive the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that i didn't passed the credentials in the right way. Now everything is working.

```
    await fetch('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/wp-login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: `log=${encodeURIComponent(EMAIL)}&pwd=${encodeURIComponent(PASSWORD)}`,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', Cache: 'no-cache' },
    })
```